# How get html content from panel in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am new to ExtJs.
I have been facing a problem in panels for getting panel html content.

```
xtype : 'panel',
id : 'first_block',
html : '<p>Hi this is belongs to first block.</p>',
listeners : {
    render : function(c) {
        c.body.on('click', function() {
            alert('' + this.id);
            alert(Ext.getCmp('first_block').items.getAt(0).getValue());
        });
}
```

I am not getting html content, but i am getting id like "first_block-body".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The `html` property defined the HTML you want in the content of your component, in this case an `Ext.Panel`.

`Ext.Panel`s create a few layers of `div`s in order to provide things like headers, footers, toolbars, etc.

If all you want is a `div` with some content, you instead want to use an `Ext.Component`.  Components don't have a `body`, so a couple things change in your code.

```
xtype : 'component',
id : 'first_block',
html : '<p>Hi this is belongs to first block.</p>',
listeners : {
    render : function(c) {
        c.on('click', function() {
            alert('' + this.id);
            alert(this.el.dom.innerHTML);
        }, this);
}
```

Notice that I added a third parameter to your `on` call, which specifies the `this` scope of the function call.  I also edited your alert to print out the innerHTML of the element, assuming that's what you were trying to do.

**UPDATE:**

If you are going to use this component in a layout, it may need to be able to have its `height` and `width` set, meaning it needs to be of type `box` in order to be an `Ext.BoxComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.getElementById('yourId').innerHTML